# Creating multiple text documents in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I am trying to create a text file filled with custom generated words in the following format: 3 numbers+2 letters+3 numbers
Example: `abc00dfe`, `aaa98fff`, and so on.

I can achieve what I want using a single text file however the file becomes so big and it is hard to handle such a big file. How can I change my code in order to save these lines in multiple text files?

```
from itertools import product
i = 1
numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
f = open("D:\wordlist" + str(i) + ".txt", "w+")
for a in product(characters, repeat=3):
    for b in product(numbers,repeat=2):
        for c in product(characters, repeat=3):
            word = "".join(a + b + c)
            f.write(word+"\n")
            i += 1
            print(str(i)+"."+word)
            if i > 13824:
                f.close()
                f = open("D:\wordlist" + str(i//13824) + ".txt", "w+")
                continue



f.close()
```

Comment: you might have forgot to reset `i` when you get to `13824`, this code looks like it will just continually open new files with one word in them once it hits `13824` words.

Comment: @Stidgeon thank you for the suggestion however I am not trying to create randomized words I am trying to make sure I get all the combinations in this form in an orderly manner.

Comment: `if i > 13824` should be `if i % 13824 == 0:` so it starts a new file every 13824 lines.

Comment: You have a small bug in your new file name. What is `str(i//13824)` when `13824 < i < 2*13824`? Its `"1"`! Thats will have the same filename as your original file. Change `str(i//13824)` to `str((i//13824) + 1)`.

Comment: Why don't you start a new file for each iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: @L.Grozinger actually this code never opens more than one file and that is the problem. console output gives starts printing from  i = 13824 which is another problem.

Comment: There's no need for `continue` at the end of the loop. Loops automatically continue unless you break out.

Comment: @Barmar your method works absolutely fine thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have everything in place, just need an extra variable(file_number) to have control of the file you are in.
At the end your code should look like

```py
from itertools import product
i = 1
file_number = 0
numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
f = open("D:\wordlist" + str(file_number) + ".txt", "w+")
for a in product(characters, repeat=3):
    for b in product(numbers,repeat=2):
        for c in product(characters, repeat=3):
            word = "".join(a + b + c)
            f.write(word+"\n")
            i += 1
            print(str(i)+"."+word)
            if i > 13824:
                f.close()
                file_number += 1
                f = open("D:\wordlist" + str(file_number) + ".txt", "w+")
                i = 1
                continue

f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however another comment has fixed the problem without adding anything. Simply changing `i > 13824`  to  `i % 13824 = 0`  makes it work.